# Pandas DataFrame: mean of column B values within column A windows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, binning

If I have a pandas DataFrame in Python such as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.uniform(0,10,20)
b = np.random.uniform(0,1,20)
data = np.vstack([a,b]).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['A','B']
df.sort_values(by=['A'])

           A         B
5   0.057519  0.465408
14  1.610972  0.398077
3   1.725556  0.397708
17  1.734124  0.600723
11  1.944105  0.694152
19  3.265799  0.878538
13  3.352460  0.770505
10  3.865299  0.064723
16  4.137863  0.659662
12  5.597172  0.122269
7   5.990105  0.667533
6   6.410582  0.193027
9   6.881429  0.041691
15  7.522877  0.268144
1   8.093155  0.130559
0   8.699004  0.996624
8   8.755095  0.495984
4   9.135271  0.792966
18  9.440045  0.477514
2   9.654226  0.509812
```

Is it possible to efficiently calculate the mean of column `B` values in intervals of column `A`?

For example one might want to calculate the mean of values in column `B` which fall into the bin ranges `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` of column `A`. So for the bin range `A = {0-1}` the mean of `B` values falling within this bin would be `0.465408`, for the bin range `A = {1-2}` the mean of B values falling within this bin would be `0.522665`, etc.

I've found `pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean` (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean.html) but it appears to calculate the mean values over a window of specified length rather than over bin widths of another column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `cut` to segment `A` column into bins, and then applying `groupby` on these segments and calculating the `mean` value of `B`:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=np.arange(11)))['B'].mean()
```

Output:

```
A
(0, 1]     0.465408
(1, 2]     0.522665
(2, 3]          NaN
(3, 4]     0.571255
(4, 5]     0.659662
(5, 6]     0.394901
(6, 7]     0.117359
(7, 8]     0.268144
(8, 9]     0.541056
(9, 10]    0.593431
```

**Update:** you can use `agg` to apply a set of different aggregation functions, such as `mean`, `std` and `size` for example:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['A'], bins=np.arange(11)))['B'].agg(['mean', 'std', 'size'])
```

Output:

```
             mean       std  size
A                                
(0, 1]   0.465408       NaN     1
(1, 2]   0.522665  0.149038     4
(2, 3]        NaN       NaN     0
(3, 4]   0.571255  0.441983     3
(4, 5]   0.659662       NaN     1
(5, 6]   0.394901  0.385560     2
(6, 7]   0.117359  0.107011     2
(7, 8]   0.268144       NaN     1
(8, 9]   0.541056  0.434788     3
(9, 10]  0.593431  0.173556     3
```

Comment: Is there a way to also return the number of values in each interval as a separate column? This way one could use `.std()` instead of `.mean()` and then divide by the number of samples to get an error on the mean in each bin.

Comment: Thanks so much, very elegant solution!

Comment: Sure, just add 'median' to the `agg` parameter list, like `.agg(['mean', 'std', 'size', 'median'])`

Comment: And to calculate the mean values for indexes, you can use `pd.IntervalIndex(df.index)`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.uniform(0,10,20)
b = np.random.uniform(0,1,20)
data = np.vstack([a,b]).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['A', 'B'])

bins = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=10)
df.groupby(bins)['B'].agg({'B': 'mean'}).reset_index()
```

You can also provide a list of bins to `pd.cut`, e.g. `bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.